# ASP.NET MVC Download and save Excel file will not ask user to download

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, download

My question in detail: I am trying to send an excel file that I created server-side (C#, MVC, ASP.NET) to the client using an HttpPost request.

The response header and content are all correctly shown (inspecting network messages shows the response data actually contains the excel), but it will not open a download as prompt.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExtractFilteredCOTs(COTJSON[] cots, string logo, string zone, string type, int numcol)
    {
        try
        {
            //some data mods...
            string fullpath = EPPlusExcelWriter.generateExcel(cotds, logo, type, zone, numcol);
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullpath);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
            Response.End();

            return null; // return base.File(fullpath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

JavaScript call:

```
        var handleError = function (data) {
            vm.addErrorAlert("Excel Extraction Failed: " + data);
        };
        var handleSuccess = function (data) {
            vm.addSuccessAlert("Excel Extraction Success");
            console.log(data);

        };
        HttpService.postRequest("/Home/ExtractFilteredCOTs", { cots: cots2, logo: vm.reportLogosChoice, zone: GMT, type: vm.reportTypesChoice, numcol: vm.reportNumCols }, handleSuccess, handleError);
```

The excel file is correctly in the console.log and in the post response, but it does not save or open.

Any clues on what I am doing wrong?
I have looked at a 100 other solutions on StackOverFlow but none seem to actually work (or I don't completely understand what the answer actually does, and blatant copy-pasting does not work).

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.